# How to get rid of "%20Profile" in URL Pattern

Tags: django, url, django-models, django-views, django-templates

First, I will search up the user, and then it takes me to a page of a list of users to click onto. After that, when I choose a user I want to click on to check out their profile, it should take me to users page I want to see, but that is where I have a problem. The URL pattern should be, for example */user/MatthewRond/*, but instead, I get */user/MatthewRond%20Profile/*, which prevents me from seeing  Matthew's page because %20Profile was never intended to be in the URL. If I can figure out how to get rid of the %20Profile, my problem should be solved.

I read up on what %20 was and what I got from it: it has to do with using and dealing with alphanumeric characters. Regardless none of it helped me figure out how to remove it. As for the code part of it, I am grabbing the default username from the database then grabbing the custom profile I made from that default user. After that, I set the username to the custom profile model I made.

views.py

```
def profile_view(request, username, *args, **kwargs,):
    context = {}
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        profile = user.profile
        img = profile.uploads_set.all().order_by("-id")

        context['username'] = user.username
    except:
        return HttpResponse("Something went wrong.")
    if profile and img:
        context = {"profile": profile, "img": img}

        return render(request, "main/profile_visit.html", context)
```

search_results.py

```
<a class="profile-link" href="{% url 'profile_view' username=profile.0 %}">
```

urls.py

```
path("user/<str:username>/", views.profile_view, name = "profile_view"),
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = False, blank = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(default = 'default.png', upload_to = "img/%y", null = True, blank = True)
    banner_picture = models.ImageField(default = 'bg_image.png', upload_to = "img/%y", null = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Comment: It might help to see the Profile class.

Comment: I added it, I don't know why I didn't.

Comment: I think it might be something in the __str__ function, now that you pointed the class out.

Comment: I think you got it.  The %20 is the code for a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Rapheal, the error would be in the Profile class. Change this

```
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

to this.

```
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

Remove the space and the Profile